# Java EE File Upload to server: can't deploy web-app

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I try to do a simple file upload to server using apache.fileupload.
I tried many tutorials and ALL of them give me same result: project can't be deployed on server.
But I can deploy my other projects, so it's definetly something wrong with Servlet class.
**Here it is**:

```
public class UploadServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements
        javax.servlet.Servlet {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String DATA_DIRECTORY = "data";
    private static final int MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
    private static final int MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Check that we have a file upload request
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

        if (!isMultipart) {
            return;
        }

        // Create a factory for disk-based file items
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        // Sets the size threshold beyond which files are written directly to disk.
        factory.setSizeThreshold(MAX_MEMORY_SIZE);

        // Sets the directory used to temporarily store files that are larger
        // than the configured size threshold. We use temporary directory for java
        factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

        // constructs the folder where uploaded file will be stored
        String uploadFolder = getServletContext().getRealPath("")
                                    + File.separator + DATA_DIRECTORY;

        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        // Set overall request size constraint
        upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

        try {
            // Parse the request
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = items.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    String filePath = uploadFolder + File.separator + fileName;
                    File uploadedFile = new File(filePath);

                    // saves the file to upload directory
                    item.write(uploadedFile);
                }
            }

            // displays done.jsp page after upload finished
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/done.jsp").forward(request, response);

        } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }       
    }
}
```

Here is my **web.xml** just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>CodeWeb</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>UploadServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>UploadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>upload.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**upload.jsp**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="UploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select file to upload:
<input type="file" name="dataFile" id="fileChooser"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**done.jsp**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload Done</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Your file has been uploaded!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to deploy it on server I get:

```
ноя 08, 2012 11:48:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;.
ноя 08, 2012 11:48:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CodeWeb' did not find a matching property.
ноя 08, 2012 11:48:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
ноя 08, 2012 11:48:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
ноя 08, 2012 11:48:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1000 ms
ноя 08, 2012 11:48:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
ноя 08, 2012 11:48:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
ноя 08, 2012 11:48:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CodeWeb]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CodeWeb]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 21 more

ноя 08, 2012 11:48:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more

ноя 08, 2012 11:48:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

ноя 08, 2012 11:48:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1092 ms
```

What am I doing wrong? Help me please!

Comment: do you have commons fileupload jar in your lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have commons-fileupload.jar in app's lib